# Rails-like templates in playframework

Tags: templates, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm looking for an alternative to [rails templates and yield](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield) in playframework, version 2.0.

Is there something similar to that? I couldn't find it by browsing the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know rails but it looks to me like what is explained here for playframework:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaTemplateUseCases

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>@title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="content">@content</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Somatik's answer Play provides a default template language that is similar to rails' ERB but it is simple enough to replace it with any template engine that you want. You might want to look into [Scalate](http://scalate.fusesource.org/) which provides template engines for Mustache and SCAML/Jade (both very similar to HAML).

This [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/J3lXeRyti4M) on the Play 2.0 Google group points to further documentation on the subject of integrating Scalate into a Play 2.0 application.